# Insert new lines with missing values (NA)

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep

I would like to insert new lines in text files if there are missing values.
I have for example the following text file (A.txt), for which line 5 is missing. In addition, as the file should have 12 lines the lines 11-12 are also missing.

```
1 2.30
2 3.01
3 3.22
4 3.34
6 3.01
7 2.90
8 2.99
9 3.00
10 3.02
```

My expected output is the following. For missing cases a line should be added with the number and NA. As you see, this happened as desired at line 5, 11 and 12:

```
1 2.30
2 3.01
3 3.22
4 3.34
5 NA
6 3.01
7 2.90
8 2.99
9 3.00
10 3.02
11 NA
12 NA
```

I am able to do this by using the following script:

```
f1=/my-directory/
echo "new file" > "$f1"/newfile.txt  

for i in {1..12}; do
l=$(awk '{print $1}' /"$f1"/A.txt | grep -wE ^$i /"$f1"/A.txt)
if grep --quiet -wE ^$i /"$f1"/A.txt; then echo "$l" >> "$f1"/newfile.txt; else echo "$i NA" >> "$f1"/newfile.txt; fi

done
```

This works fine. The problem is however that I need to do this for about 600 files containing more than about 160000 lines. The loop solution would therefore take too much time searching through all lines. My question is: is there a simpler solution that could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an `awk` script:

```
awk '{ while (NR + shift < $1) { print (NR + shift) " NA"; shift++ }; print } END { shift++; while (NR + shift < 13) { print (NR + shift) " NA"; shift++ } }' /tmp/test1
```

will produce the required output for `/tmp/test1` (replace that with each file you wish to process).

In a more readable form:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    while (NR + shift < $1) {
        print (NR + shift) " NA"
        shift++
    }
    print
}
END {
    shift++
    while (NR + shift < 13) {
        print (NR + shift) " NA"
        shift++
    }
}
```

Save this as a file, say `fill-missing`, make it executable, then you can simply run

```
./fill-missing /tmp/test1
```

The script processes each line, keeping track of the expected delta with the current line number in `shift`. So for every line, if the current line adjusted doesn't match the first number in the line, it prints the appropriate line number followed by `NA` and increments the delta; once the line numbers match, it prints the current line. At the end of the process, it prints any missing lines required to reach 12.

Answer (score 5):

[`join`](http://man.cx/join) works well here:

```
join -a 1 -o 0,2.2 -e NA  <(seq 12)  A.txt  2>/dev/null
```

I throw away stderr because `join` complains if  the join field is not *lexically* sorted.

Comment: This fails on the last line of input given in [Adding the missing number in the sequence and introduce zero in corresponding column \ duplicate](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294319/adding-the-missing-number-in-the-sequence-and-introduce-zero-in-corresponding-co?lq=1).  Additional sorting is [one way to fix it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190706/insert-new-lines-with-missing-values-na/294377#294377).

Answer (score 2):

the awk file

```
BEGIN { i=1 ; }
function upto(x) { while (i<x) printf "%d NA\n",i++ ;}
 { if ( $1 == i ) print ; upto($1) ; i++ ;}
END { upto(final+1) ;}
```

to be called with

```
awk -f nl.awk -v final=12 /tmp/test1
```

your whole loop

```
cd /my/directory
ls | while read f
do
      awk -f ~/nl.awk -v final=12 $f > /an/other/dir/$f
done
```

where

- you put awk program in your $HOME dir (`~/nl.awk` )

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.txt') as f:
    check = 0
    for line in f:
        if int(line.split()[0]) == check + 1:
            check = int(line.split()[0])
            print line.rstrip()
        else:
            check = int(line.split()[0])
            print int(line.split()[0]) - 1, 'NA'
            print line.rstrip()
    print int(line.split()[0]) + 1, 'NA'
    print int(line.split()[0]) + 2, 'NA'
```

Here we are comparing the line number `int(line.split()[0])` with `check + 1`, we have set initial value of `check` as `0`. If the values are equal we have printed the line, otherwise we have printed the desired content i.e. missing line number and `NA`. The last two lines are used to print the 11th and 12th lines.

Answer (score 0):

Glenn Jackman's `bash` and `join` method with a few tweaks, this function gets the count from the input file, and uses that count as a default:

```
# Usage: inlwmv file [ missing_value [ extra_lines ] ]
#      if unset, missing_value="NA", and extra_lines=0
inlwmv() { join -a 1  -o 0,2.2  -e "${2:-NA}" \
           <(seq $((${3:-0} + $(tail -n 1 "$1" | cut -d ' ' -f1))) | sort -k 1b,1)  \
           <(sort -k 1b,1 "$1") | \
           sort -g ; }
```

For the OP question:

```
inlwmv A.file "" 2
```

For [this duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294319/adding-the-missing-number-in-the-sequence-and-introduce-zero-in-corresponding-co?lq=1) the Jackman version fails on the last value of *afile*, (`join` is quite finicky about ordering, but using `sort` three times makes it behave as required):

```
inlwmv afile 0
```

Comment: Defaulting to STDIN would be nice, if the *filename* were missing.