# Add a line if it's missing

Tags: shell-script, osx

I have a data gathering device which records per second. Sometimes, randomly it drops a second or more. For example

```
166,1.09424,240,76,132
168,1.10088,215,76,132
169,1.10765,213,78,131
170,1.11458,198,79,131
```

It can gather 1M data points in a session, and might miss >100

Looking around I found this AWK command

```
awk '{ while (NR + shift < $1) { print (NR + shift) " NA"; shift++ }; print } END { shift++; while (NR + shift < 13) { print (NR + shift) " NA"; shift++ } }' /tmp/test1
```

from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190706/insert-new-lines-with-missing-values-na)

but that gives new lines when they aren't needed:

```
166 NA
167 NA
168 NA
169 NA
170 NA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with your command line:

1. Your CSV uses comma delimiters, but your `awk` command assumes the default space delimiter. This is the primary reason you get unnecessary fills.
2. The `END` case in your command exists only to fill the end result to a total minimum of 12 lines. This should therefore be removed, or the test should be changed to a higher minimum, perhaps user-specified.
3. Most tools used to process CSV don't like lines with varying numbers of fields. Your padding lines should therefore contain the same number of fields as normal lines.

Taken all together, and assuming your first record starts with second `1`, we have this:

```
awk -F, -v min_secs=2000 '
{ 
  while (NR + shift < $1) {
    print (NR + shift) ",NA,NA,NA,NA"
    shift++ 
  }
  print
}
END {
  while (NR + shift <= min_secs) {
    print (NR + shift) ",NA,NA,NA,NA"
    shift++ 
  }
}
' /tmp/test1
```

Comment: I tried to make it into one line

awk -F, -v min_secs=2000 ' {while (NR + shift < $1) {print (NR + shift) ",NA,NA,NA,NA"     shift++}print} END {while (NR + shift <= min_secs) {print (NR + shift) ",NA,NA,NA,NA" shift++}} ' wrong.txt > fixed.txt

and then ran it, however it didn't add the new line

166,1.09424,240,76,132

168,1.10088,215,76,132

169,1.10765,213,78,131

170,1.11458,198,79,131

but it also added a bunch at the end - as a test I used a small sample file that stops at 300 lines

300,2.08307,331,58,111

301,2.08754,361,60,112

301,NA,NA,NA,NA1

302,NA,NA,NA,NA2

Comment: Oh that doesn't format very well - you can see I'm a noob!

Comment: @SteveShiny If you're squeezing it all into a one-liner (which I don't recommend for clarity reasons), you have to put the semicolons between the `print` and `shift++` statements back in. That's why you're seeing increasing serial numbers at the end of each dummy line: `print` thinks `shift++` is another argument to it, instead of an entirely separate statement.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I copied and pasted the command, and got the same result. I'm on Mac if that makes a difference?

Comment: Actually I partially take that back... it found one missing point and added a line for that, but not another

223,1.59792,373,68,110  
224,1.60427,373,66,109  
225,NA,NA,NA,NA  
226,1.61923,373,63,110  
227,1.62166,373,60,110  

165,1.08769,223,77,131  
166,1.09424,240,76,132  
168,1.10088,215,76,132  
169,1.10765,213,78,131<br/>grrr how to do new lines?

Comment: @SteveShiny Your `awk` script assumes a _monotonically increasing_ serial field, i.e. `n(row+1)` must equal `n(row) + 1` for all rows. This is a standard expectation for almost all data sets, but the sample you just posted does _not_ meet that constraint. If this is a case that you need to be handled, edit your question to specify _exactly_ what should happen. A set of "before" and "after" samples, highlighting **all**  the possible data quality issues and showing the sanitized final result, would be best.

Comment: OK, I'll start a new question that's better formed

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500998/add-lines-if-they-are-missing-from-a-data-series