# Add lines if they are missing from a data series

Tags: shell-script, osx

I have a data gathering device which records 5 attributes of data per second. The first column of the data is the time elapsed, in seconds, and is always sequential ie n+1. Data fields are comma delimited.

Randomly, the device doesn't record a sample and thus in the file there a skip of a second, and sometimes more. For example below sample number 167 is missing

```
166,1.09424,240,76,132
168,1.10088,215,76,132
169,1.10765,213,78,131
170,1.11458,198,79,131
```

and in this one, 294 and 295 are missing

```
292,2.04078,285,66,108
293,2.04673,302,64,108
296,2.06309,306,67,109
297,2.06859,370,66,109
```

The collected data will have an arbitrary number of lines/samples up to 1 million of more data points in a session. The number of dropped samples could be over 200, scattered randomly throughout.

I'm looking for a script or command that runs through the file and if a line is missing, will add a new line, and add the time stamp/sample number like this

```
166,1.09424,240,76,132
167
168,1.10088,215,76,132
169,1.10765,213,78,131
170,1.11458,198,79,131
```

or this

```
292,2.04078,285,66,108
293,2.04673,302,64,108
294
295
296,2.06309,306,67,109
297,2.06859,370,66,109
```

I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190706/insert-new-lines-with-missing-values-na) which is a partial answer but gives lots of wrong new lines. I asked this question in a [less precise form](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500969/add-a-line-if-its-missing) and got a better answer but it still didn't get me the solution.

Would prefer BASH script, using commands that run on OSX 10.14.2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a comment to [my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500980/98480), you presented a dataset whose serial numbers went from 223 to 227, then dropped back to 165 through 169. Is that in a single file, and what should happen then?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a one-liner for you

```
awk -F, 'n==""||n>$1{n=$1}{while(n!=$1){print n++}}{print;n++}' < input > output
```

though it's not much different to what you had before, except the "protection" for the case when the number series suddenly warps to a lower number.